# react-scripts proxy a http/https server is loading the web in response

Tags: proxy, create-react-app, react-scripts

i am having a https create-react-app application(https://xyz.site.com), i am proxing a server which is a different domain, when i am loading the application the api is giving the web html data as a response, there is no hit happened in the server,

i have tried using `HTTPS=true` in .env file, still i am not able to get the server response

setupProxy.js

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, // https://xxx-alb-23333.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
            changeOrigin: true,
        }),
    );
};
```

Comment: If I had to guess it probably has something to do with the cookies, but not sure. I have a setupProxy.js file that can handle this, you can click to my email right from my github here: http://github.com/devinrhode2 It's not published on github but happy to give it MIT license for you

Comment: Something you should do is compare the http response and request headers with the failing case and successful case. You can then copy paste the headers into diffchecker.com. Use an incognito window, or better yet, a "Guest" chrome user, (click your chrome user/gmail icon in chrome, next to the vertical "..."). Note that you'll get a `Set-Cookie` header when you first visit the site. I'm guessing there's a `secure;` flag on the end of this header, which will need to be stripped off, assuming you want to develop on `http://localhost:3000` (not https)